# Create images from PDF file pages in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscriptsharp

I want to get images from PDF file pages. I know that a good solution is to use ghostscriptsharp. It has a special method to get a single page or multiple pages.

```
GeneratePageThumbs(string inputPath, string outputPath, int firstPage, int lastPage, int width, int height)
```

Here is my complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GhostscriptSharp;

namespace GetPages
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumbs(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\English_Medium_Extra_for_WEB-2.pdf",
                @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Test", 1, 3, 130, 130);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I use this method I have exception.

> ExternalException
>   Ghostscript conversion error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i fix this!The problem lies in the fact that 2 parameter should be the name of your image you get as a result, not a path where to save the image!
Here is the code works correctly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GhostscriptSharp;

namespace GetPages
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GhostscriptWrapper.GeneratePageThumbs(@"C:\Users\User\Downloads\English_Medium_Extra_for_WEB-2.pdf",
                "Example.png", 1, 3, 130, 130);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!Question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

replace `"Example.png"` by `"Example%d.png"` to get all 3 Pages.